# Model training in google colab seems to get stuck right before its supposed to start the epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

i'm stuck here while running sign language detection in colab. I've checked my gpu memory to see if i've maxed out the limit but it does not seem so. Colab stops at the last line of the error without going through the epochs or steps. Is there anything else that can cause this?
[This is the full code.](https://github.com/nicknochnack/TFODCourse/blob/main/2.%20Training%20and%20Detection.ipynb)

```
2021-06-09 04:08:41.983113: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-06-09 04:08:44.004791: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-06-09 04:08:44.032512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.033091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
2021-06-09 04:08:44.033136: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-06-09 04:08:44.035874: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-06-09 04:08:44.035959: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-06-09 04:08:44.037998: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-06-09 04:08:44.038400: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-06-09 04:08:44.040331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-06-09 04:08:44.040962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-06-09 04:08:44.041142: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-06-09 04:08:44.041242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.041845: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.042380: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-09 04:08:44.042701: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX512F
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-06-09 04:08:44.042929: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.043492: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
2021-06-09 04:08:44.043573: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.044144: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.044884: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-09 04:08:44.044940: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-06-09 04:08:44.534882: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-06-09 04:08:44.534939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2021-06-09 04:08:44.534954: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N 
2021-06-09 04:08:44.535140: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.535801: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.536375: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-09 04:08:44.536902: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2021-06-09 04:08:44.536950: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 13837 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
W0609 04:08:44.538746 140451613841280 mirrored_strategy.py:379] Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0609 04:08:44.541552 140451613841280 mirrored_strategy.py:369] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: 20
I0609 04:08:44.545092 140451613841280 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: 20
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0609 04:08:44.545237 140451613841280 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:558: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0609 04:08:44.566011 140451613841280 deprecation.py:336] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:558: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/train.record']
I0609 04:08:44.569845 140451613841280 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted datasets: ['Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/train.record']
I0609 04:08:44.570012 140451613841280 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record datasets for input file: ['Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0609 04:08:44.570096 140451613841280 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0609 04:08:44.570174 140451613841280 dataset_builder.py:88] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:105: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W0609 04:08:44.572111 140451613841280 deprecation.py:336] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:105: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:237: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0609 04:08:44.589101 140451613841280 deprecation.py:336] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:237: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0609 04:08:50.987270 140451613841280 deprecation.py:336] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0609 04:08:53.860780 140451613841280 deprecation.py:336] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py:464: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0609 04:08:55.375038 140451613841280 deprecation.py:336] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py:464: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
2021-06-09 04:08:57.420286: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
**2021-06-09 04:08:57.426522: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:114] CPU Frequency: 2000204999 Hz**
```

Comment: These are deprecation warnings. You can update your code as suggested in warnings.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested in deprecated message?

Comment: Yh that did not work. But i found out the problem came from the train and test images folders being untared into the wrong path.

Comment: If you found the solution, can you share the solution in answer section for the benefit of community.Thanks!